# Configuring RIAK to use non-homogenous servers as nodes

Tags: riak

I'm planning on putting together a cluster using Riak.  The servers that I'll be using come with a variety of RAM and disk storage; some have 32GB RAM, others have 96GB. Some 1TB disk space, others 12TB.

My question: how can I configure RIAK to fully utilize the resources across all servers? I'm assuming it won't automatically understand the resources it can use per server.

Comment: i wonder if you have read through basic cluster setup and configuration., have you?

Comment: Yes.  The closest param I can finds is the ring_creation_size, which states that "By default, each Riak node will own ring_creation_size/(number of nodes in the cluster) partitions."

However, I don't see how to configure a server to use more than this default.

Comment: It is unfortunate that ring size is currently a 
static parameter that you need to size properly from the onset. There 
are plans to support dynamic resizing of the ring, but those changes 
won't land any sooner in this year.

Answer (score 1):

Riak currently assumes homogenous nodes and will always attempt to spread load and data evenly across physical nodes. There is unfortunately no built in way to achieve what you are trying to do.